# JavaScript regex(?!) not working on text containing literal \n\r?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match some characters in a text that contains `\n\r`:

```
`start[\n\r]other words end other words`.match(/start(?!end)./)
```

expect to:

```
start[\n\r]other words
```

but got:

```
start[
```

What's the problem, why I get this error result?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not a literal `\n\r` - it's interpreted as a newline

Comment: Also, even even if you had literal newlines, the regex will give you the same result. You're looking for the exact match `start` that is **not** followed by the exact match `end` and then get the next character. So, matching `start.` unless there is `end` immediately after the `start`. In your string, that resolves as `start[` regardless of whether you have a literal `\n` sequence or a newline.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with the newline. Ignoring the look-ahead, your regex is only asking to match the word `start` and one additional character `/start./`, so that's exactly what you are getting. What you actually want is to match `start` and everthing up to, but not including, `end`. You can do that with `start.*?(?=end)`.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to match

1. everything until there is `end`, or
2. matching everything up to a point where it is not `end` to the right (so it'd one character less (1) above

In NodeJS:

```js
    console.log(`start[\n\r]other words end other words`.match(/(start.*?)end/s)[1])
    // => 'start[\n\r]other words '
    
    console.log(`start[\n\r]other words end other words`.match(/(start.*?).end/s)[1])  
    // => 'start[\n\r]other words'
```

The modifier `s` let the `.` match newline characters.

Note that

```
`start[\n\r]other words end other words`.match(/(start.*)(?!end)/s)[1]
// => 'start[\n\r]other words end other words'
```

because the result satisfied "matching `start` and any length of string, and then it doesn't have `end` to the right).

and

```
`start[\n\r]other words end other words`.match(/(start.*?)(?!end)/s)[1]
// => 'start'
```

satisfied "matching `start` and any length of string and don't be greedy, and then it doesn't have `end` to the right).